# Unity2D - natural physics for two colliding spheres/balls

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my 2D Unity game, balls can bounce off each other. My goal is to have them bounce off each other as you would expect physically in the real world.

The only difference is that the speed of the balls decreases, but they can never come to a stop.

I have different approaches to map the physical behavior. But none of them leads to a good result.

(1)

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
var point = collision.GetContact(0);
var curDire = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up);
var newDir = Vector2.Reflect(curDire, point.normal);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector2.up, newDir);
speed *= 0.75f;
}
```

I don't know how describe exactly: It can happen that the balls push past each other. They collide, but do not bounce off each other, but maintain their direction.

Another approach I have read about is to add an `AddForce` to the `velocity` of `Rigidbody2D`.
Then the following code should do the physics.

```
private void Start()
{
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
_velocity = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f);
_rb.AddForce(_velocity, ForceMode2D.Force);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {

var inDirection = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
var inNormal = collision.contacts[0].point;
var newVelocity = Vector2.Reflect(inDirection, inNormal);
rb.velocity = newVelocity;
}
```

The results are really random. I think I use a wrong `AddForce` or the `velocity`-Vector is strange. I fall here the deeper mathematical understanding to fully comprehend this solution.

(3) Then I read about Physic Material 2D. This sounds best. I created one (Asset -> Create -> 2D -> Physic Material 2D). Set `bounciness` to 1 the `friction` to 0.1. I select my Ball-prefab and add the physic material to my collider. I added it to the `Rigidbody2D`, too. But this asset has no effect. (My balls have no gravity. I don't know if this is important.)

I imagine Unity has a super simple solution for this problem. But I just can't find it. Does anyone have any ideas or approaches for me? I actually just want shot balls to bounce off each other. This should look as much as possible like it would look in real life.

**Update Question**
I move the ball like that

```
 private Vector3 _inDirection;

 private void Start()
{
_inDirection = Vector3.right * (speed * Time.deltaTime * (_didCollide ? -1 : 1)); 
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
transform.Translate(_inDirection);
}
```

Comment: So you set it’s velocity, and try calculate the bounce direction. Why not just leave it all to the physics  engine?

Comment: I tried different approaches. In case 3 I just set the physic engine and do not set any velocity manually. But the physic engine does not work. I do anything wrong in the implementation.

Comment: Well. The physics does work. So when you said you weren’t setting velocity what did you set?

Comment: I did it like case (3) in my original question. Add the physic material 2d, drag it to the collider of the ball prefab and that’s it. I thought that this is enough. The collider has no trigger. Do you need the exact config?

Comment: Don’t reference other questions if you can’t explain how you moved it that’s a worry. And no it’s not the collider. Im asking how you moved the things around.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I updated my question. I init a `Vektor3` and update him in `FixedUpdate()`

Comment: Define “update him” how. What did you do to move the ball?

Comment: For detail please see my question. I init the direction in Start() and in FixedUpdate() the value is updated. I use „transform.Translate“ for moving

Comment: That’s not using physics to move. That’s why it didn’t work

Comment: How do I have to move my ball? Do you have a hint? Does ist work when I use AddForce?

Comment: That should work

Comment: I just use `rigidbody.velocity` instead of `Translate` and everything works like expeceted - thanks